# Легальное использование open source библиотек в своих проектах

Tags: библиотеки, лицензирование, opensource

Я делаю проект, в котором собираюсь использовать open source библиотеку. Библиотека имеет лицензию MIT, Apache 2.0, BSD, LGPL или свою лицензию типа, например, как в CURL:

> COPYRIGHT AND PERMISSION NOTICE
>
> Copyright (c) 1996 - 2024, Daniel Stenberg, daniel@haxx.se, and many
> contributors, see the THANKS file.
>
> All rights reserved.
>
> Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software for any
> purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
> copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
> EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT
> OF THIRD PARTY RIGHTS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
> HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
> IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR
> IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
> SOFTWARE.
>
> Except as contained in this notice, the name of a copyright holder
> shall not be used in advertising or otherwise to promote the sale, use
> or other dealings in this Software without prior written authorization
> of the copyright holder.

Далее 2 варианта:

1. Я делаю проект с закрытым исходным кодом (распространяю его в виде бинарей).
2. Я делаю проект с открытым исходным кодом.

Как мне юридически правильно сослаться на использование библиотеки? Нужно ли включать тексты лицензий? В каких файлах их хранить и каким образом (например, если я использую несколько разных библиотек)?

В первом случае это можно сделать либо в документации, либо выводить при запуске программы (например, с каким-то ключом или в разделе "О программе"). Но опять-таки, что именно выводить?

Во втором, нужно ли включать лицензионный текст (и вообще ссылку на библиотеку), если исходные коды и файлы лицензии лежат в отдельных папках в исходниках моего проекта? А если я их не включаю, а просто хочу написать, что "библиотеку CURL можно скачать отсюда: URL".

В общем, как это правильно оформить в каждом из случаев? Спасибо!

Comment: Ну например прям в браузере можете набрать `about:credits` и увидеть как сделано в нём

Comment: @andreymal, как пример ок, но это не исчерпывающий ответ. То есть, возможны ли другие варианты? Например, просто написать: "*В проекте используется библиотека CURL: https://...*"? И т.п. У меня вообще много вопросов выше :)

Comment: «В проекте используется библиотека CURL» — это не the above copyright notice и не this permission notice, поэтому так нельзя

Comment: @andreymal, ссылка на лицензию тоже не годится? То есть нужно обязательно прямо-таки весь текст лицензии прописывать? Опять же,что делать с файлом THANKS?

Comment: Нет гарантий, что ссылка будет жива вечно, поэтому не надо (а GNU вообще явно [запрещает](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhyMustIInclude), например)

Comment: @andreymal, а что делать с файлом THANKS ?